# Solving a system of partial derivatives.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

$uu_{x} - vv_{y} = 0$

$uu_{y} + vv_{x} = 0$

The subscripts represent partial derivatives. In general, the solution to this system should just be $0$. Not sure how to get that though. I was playing around with like one would do using elimination on linear systems but could not get the solution.

Comment: Is the last one $vu_x$ or $vv_x$?

Comment: Whoops its $vv_{x}$. I will fix that.

Comment: These are then the Cauchy-Riemann equations for $u^2$and $v^2$. Take any holomorphic function $f$, and $u = \sqrt{\Re f}, \; v = \sqrt{\Im f}$ will satisfy the system where defined. If you want global solutions (defined on the entire plane), you get only constants, but local solutions are plenty.

Comment: Let me ask you this. Suppose I had the equations $2uu_{x} + 2vv_{x} = 0$ and $2uu_{y} + 2vv_{y} = 0$, could I apply the Cauchy Riemann equations to rewrite them like the ones I mentioned in my question then?

Comment: No, that's a different kind of function. These equations say that $u^2 + v^2 \equiv \mathrm{const}$.